# Angularjs: Multiple file-uploader in a single page

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-directive

I am facing lot of problem in while using more than 1 file uploader in single page. There is any directive for this? because I didn't find it. By the way I am using [Bruno Angularjs uploader Directive](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/a-directive-to-manage-file-upload-in-an-angularjs-application) and tried to change multiple but getting problem while form submitting beacause all uploaders sharing same model so thats why I was not able to get all the values at a time only one can be access.
          So if anyone have some solution or suggestion for this, please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good jquery ajax uploader which is available in angualar js version also.
Please check here http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html

Comment: No I don't want to upload multiple files, I want to use more than one file uploader in a single page. like 
`<input type="file" name="file1"> <input type="file" name="file2"> <input type="submit" value="save">`

Comment: Yes, you can do the same with this try the demo by adding files one by one and click main ``start upload``